# Joining two querys with query builder Laravel

Tags: laravel

I made this query to filter the repeated data from rif

```
$incidencias2 = DB::table('incidencias')
->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT(rif)'));
```

And I want to join my first query with this second query for avoid the repeated data from rif

```
$av2 = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(cat_cliente) as av2'), 'cat_cliente')
    ->whereIn('cat_cliente', ['AV'])
    ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
    ->get();
```

How could I do that? can somebody help me?